# If dynamically added script already exists, how to not add it again?

Tags: javascript

In the script below, on click, I'm adding scripts to the head of the DOM. Once that's done, then the accompanying video will play. However, if I dismiss the video, and click the event handler again, it adds the script to the head again. And it continues to do this as long as I continue to click the button.

**If the script already exists in the head, how do I prevent it from being added again?**

```js
const getVideoId = (wistia_vid) => {
  const classes = Array.from(wistia_vid.querySelector(".wistia_embed").classList);
  const idClass = classes.find((cls) => cls.startsWith("wistia_async_"));
  const id = idClass.replace("wistia_async_", "");

  return id;
};
const removeElems = (wistia_vid) => {
  const toRemove = Array.from(
    wistia_vid.querySelectorAll(".wistia__overlay, .embed-youtube__play, .embed-video__play")
  );

  toRemove.forEach((node) => node.remove());
};

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".wistia")).forEach((node) => {
  node.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const videoId = getVideoId(node);
    let wistiaSupportScripts = [
      //adds jsonp file to provide security over requests
      `https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/${videoId}.jsonp`,
      `https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js`
    ];

    removeElems(node);

    //loads supporting scripts into head
    for (var i = 0; i < wistiaSupportScripts.length; i++) {
      let wistiaSupportScript = document.createElement("script");
      wistiaSupportScript.src = wistiaSupportScripts[i];
      let complete = false;
      if (!complete &&
        (!this.readyState ||
          this.readyState == "loaded" ||
          this.readyState == "complete")
      ) {
        complete = true;
        console.log(`Scripts were added.`);
      }

      let wistiaContainers = document.querySelector(".wistia");

      wistiaContainers
        ?
        document
        .getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
        .appendChild(wistiaSupportScript) :
        console.log("No Wistia videos here.");
    }

    window._wq = window._wq || [];
    _wq.push({
      //globally scoped
      id: videoId,
      options: {
        autoPlay: true,
        volume: 0.5
      },

      onReady: function(video) {
        playedOnce = true;
        video.popover.show();
        video.play();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wistia">
  <span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_vhkqhqhzyq popover=true popoverContent=link">
    <a href="#oquote-hero-section" class="button">
      <span class="btn__txt">Meet the team</span>
  </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script>` tags are still HTML elements.
Which means you can assign unique `id`s to them and check if they exist in DOM using `document.querySelector('#script-id')` or `document.getElementById('script-id')`.

Example:

```js
function addScript(id, url) {
  if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = id;
    script.onload = function() {
      console.log("Script loaded and ready");
    };
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  } else {
    console.log(`Script with id \`${id}\` has already been added!`)
  } 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addScript('my-unique-id', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js')">Add script</button>
```

Comment: I have to see how this will apply to my situation. I'm not using an onclick in my markup, so I'll have to make some adjustments and circle back.

Comment: The `onclick` is completely irrelevant. ***Whenever*** you want to add the script and ***regardless*** of what triggers it, determine the `id` of the script to add and check if it exists. If it doesn't, add it, and give it the `id`. When/if that code runs again, it will check if the script exists and this time it will find the script, so it won't add it again.

Comment: It's hard to add a readable code snippet in comments, so I've created a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/eYGWNBM), based on your feedback. When I click the trigger for the second time, it returns **"Script with id `[object PointerEvent]` has already been added!"**.

I don't understand the `[object PointerEvent]` being returned.

Comment: @Millhorn, `[object PointerEvent]` is the click event itself, because you're not passing arguments to the `addScript` function and, by default, any onclick handler receives the event as an argument. In the code above, I'm specifically passing arguments to the function. Anyways, it looks like you don't need the arguments. See it working here: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/OJxmMgG